# IE Vendor prefix/non-prefix Transform Translate not working

Tags: javascript, css

I've written a short bit of HTML that allows the user to click a button and watch a slide come into view.

This is the function that runs the 'animation':

```
function startSlideQuestions(start_slide) {
var startSlide = document.getElementById(start_slide);
startSlide.style.webkitTransform = "translate(0, -100%)";
startSlide.style.transform = "translate(0, -100%)";
}
```

It pulls a div from the bottom of the screen into view by translating it its own height from the bottom.

This works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera but does nothing in Internet Explorer.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which version of IE. What about `-ms-transform`?

Comment: I've tried using
    startSlide.style.msTransform = "translate(0, -100%)";

Comment: No luck with style.MsTransform or style.msTransform :(

Comment: Your function works for me in IE11 (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0cmn1bn7/)). Here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/5CDYuZZ.png) of what the style pane looks like. Could you set up a fiddle/snippet showing how you're calling this?

Comment: I've set this up - having bother trying to get it to work tho http://jsfiddle.net/gregsby15/pLg64jmq/

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your fiddle on this PC and seeing it didn't work, I went on another machine and found it DID work. Both machines on same OS and version of IE. Turns out it was a problem with browser and after a reset to factory settings and a reboot the fiddle and my code work